# Скрыть панель при нажатии за пределами этой панели

Tags: c#, winforms

Panel1 по умолчанию скрыта и открывается по нажатию на button. Нужно чтобы она закрывалась сама если пользователь нажмет в любом месте, кроме самой panel1.

Comment: `Panel` сама по себе не захватывает фокус. Нужно смотреть в сторону изменения её стиля на `Selectable` - [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/5045688).

Answer (score 2):

Оп-па! Кто бы мог предположить?

Свойство класса `System.Windows.Forms.Control`

```
public bool Capture { get; set; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture(v=vs.110).aspx

> When a control has captured the mouse, it receives mouse input whether
>   or not the cursor is within its borders.
>
> После того, как элемент управления захватил мышь, он получает события мыши независимо от
>   того, находится ли мышь внутри или вне этого контрола.

Назначаете `panel.Capture = true;` и в обработчике `MouseDown` этой панели проверяете координаты в аргументе события мыши - `MouseEventArgs`.

Comment: беру свои слова назад, последнее время только бекэндом занимался. забыл =(

Comment: Нет, это не то. Тем более тс нужно проверять потерю фокуса, а не захват.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Пардон, где в вопросе слово "фокус"?

Comment: Если бы панель захватывала фокус, то вопрос решался бы элементарно (реакцией на событие потери фокуса). А свойство `Capture` устанавливается в `true`, когда нажата кнопка мыши на этом контроле. Отпускаем кнопку - станем `false`. Но нужен-то клик за пределами панели. Для этого либо **все** контролы на форме нужно подписывать и при их клике скрывать панель, либо делать панель фокусируемой.